# fadeIn and Fadeout css background color not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

FadeIn and FadeOut background color not changing.

when I click on whatup link my button should blink with red and white colors below is code for html

```
<a id="blkwhatsup" href="#" >whats up</a>
<input id="blkbtn" type="submit" value="2">
```

Below is code for jquery when I click on whatup link my button should blink with fadein and fadeout.it's blinking but background color not changing for button

```
$('#blkwhatsup').click(function(e) {  
    interval = setInterval(function() { 
         $('#blkbtn').fadeOut({ backgroundColor: '#90191c',color:'#fff', border: '1px solid #90191c' }, 300) 
         $('#blkbtn').fadeIn( { backgroundColor:'#fff', color: '#90191c', border: '1px solid #90191c'}, 300); 
    }, 1000); 
});
```

Comment: The methods don't allow to pass properties. http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 0):

> Here is an example that will works fine for fadeOut & fadeIn background colors

```js
$('#doit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#fadeout-div').show().delay(500).fadeOut(1100);
});
```

```css
#wrapping-div {
 height:200px;
 width:300px;
 border:1px solid #999;
 padding:1px 8px;
 background-color: #fff;
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
}

#fadeout-div {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 background-color: #ffd700;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:-1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><a href="#!/doit" id="doit">fadeOut/fadeIn</a></p>

<div id="wrapping-div">
  <p>This is some text</p>
  <p>This is some text</p>
  <p>This is some text</p>
  <div id="fadeout-div"></div>
</div>
```